# Using jQuery UI datepicker to pick the date a specific location

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I want to use jQueryUI datepicker in the same way you'd see it in use for booking a flight from London airport.

By this I mean, the selection should show the same dates available, regardless of timezone.

The minDate/maxDate (as well as unavailable dates within that range) are sent from the server. However, when trying to use these the date picker renders different available dates if you change your computer's timezone.

```
var serverData = {
    minDate: '2014-09-04T00:00:00Z',
    maxDate: '2014-09-06T00:00:00Z'
};


$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    minDate: moment(serverData.minDate).toDate(),
    maxDate: moment(serverData.maxDate).toDate()
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kmgkLyyx/  (try using London-UTC+1 vs. timezones at either end of the spectrum)

How can I just render a set of available dates (based on this data from the server) and not have it jump around depending on your locale (i.e. how can I make it "time agnostic")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the time off before passing the date string to moment.

```
var serverData = {
    minDate: '2014-09-04T00:00:00Z',
    maxDate: '2014-09-06T00:00:00Z'
};


$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    minDate: moment(serverData.minDate.substring(0,10)).toDate(),
    maxDate: moment(serverData.maxDate.substring(0,10)).toDate()
});
```